# Mount multiple directories using ecryptfs

Tags: debian, ecryptfs

I am using ecryptyfs to store some sensitive data in my PC (Debian wheezy). The data is in a partition and the partition is mounted automatically on bootup using `/etc/fstab` I have setup `/root/.ecryptfsrc` with correct parameters. Contents of my `.ecryptfsrc` are as follows:

```
key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=/mnt/usb/password.txt
ecryptfs_sig=deadbeefdeadbeef
ecryptfs_cipher=aes
ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
ecryptfs_passthrough=n
ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n
```

This partition is correctly getting mounted after a system reboot. So far fine.

I also need to transport this sensitive data to remote place in a USB drive. So I want to format a usb drive with ext2 fs and mount it using ecryptfs. I also do not want to reuse the password and want to give an one time password to each USB drive when the ecryptfs is mounted.

Formatting and mounting of ext2 partition works as expected. The command I used for mounting the new usb device using ecryptfs is as follows. the password is stored (temporarily) in `/root/usbpasswd.txt` :

```
mount  -t ecryptfs  \
-o "rw,key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=/root/usbpasswd.txt,\
ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,\
ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=y" \
/mnt/usb2/ /mnt/usb2/
```

Instead of mounting the freshly formatted `/mnt/usb2` using password in file, I an prompted for `Passphrase File` as follows:

```
Passphrase File: /root/usbpasswd.txt
Passphrase File: /mnt/usb/password.txt
Passphrase File: /root/usbpasswd.txt
Passphrase File: ^C
```

What could be wrong here?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2):

I have had exactly the same problem.

While in the manual it's written to use

```
-o key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=/root/usbpasswd.txt
```

the working command has a different option:

```
-o passphrase_passwd_file=/root/usbpasswd.txt
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.